# How do closures work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading about the math foundation behind Haskell - I've learned about how closures can be used to save state in a function.

I was wondering if Haskell allows closures, and how they work because they are not pure functions?

If a function modifies it's closed-over state it will be capable of giving different outputs on identical inputs.

How is this not a problem in Haskell? Is it because you can't reassign a variable after you initially assign it a value?

Comment: Simply, you can't modify the closed-over state or any other :)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419175/are-closures-a-violation-of-the-functional-programming-paradigm/

Comment: @is7s but you can cause it to be instantiated further between calls, if it's a non-atomic data.

Comment: Haskell does not have mutable closures. Every value is (potentially) an immutable closure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closure just 'adds' additional variables to function, so there is nothing more you can do with them than you can with 'normal' ones, that is, certainly not modify the state.

Read more:
[Closures (in Haskell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088295/closures-in-haskell)

Comment: Ok thanks, accepting this answer for the beginner's intuition language

Comment: Does haskell consider the closured variables to be values or references?

Comment: I think you'd have to first elaborate what you mean when saying 'reference', as it can lead to some confusion considering we're in pure Haskell world.

Answer (score 10):

You actually can simulate closures in Haskell, but not the way you might think.  First, I will define a closure type:

```
data Closure i o = Respond (i -> (o, Closure i o ))
```

This defines a type that at each "step" takes a value of type `i` which is used to compute a response of type `o`.

So, let's define a "closure" that accepts empty inputs and answers with integers, i.e.:

```
incrementer :: Closure () Int
```

This closure's behavior will vary from request to request.  I'll keep it simple and make it so that it responds with 0 to the first response and then increments its response for each successive request:

```
incrementer = go 0 where
    go n = Respond $ \() -> (n, go (n + 1))
```

We can then repeatedly query the closure, which yields a result and a new closure:

```
query :: i -> Closure i o -> (o, Closure i o)
query i (Respond f) = f i
```

Notice that the second half of the above type resembles a common pattern in Haskell, which is the `State` monad:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }
```

It can be imported from `Control.Monad.State`. So we can wrap `query` in this `State` monad:

```
query :: i -> State (Closure i o) o
query i = state $ \(Respond f) -> f i
```

... and now we have a generic way to query any closure using the `State` monad:

```
someQuery :: State (Closure () Int) (Int, Int)
someQuery = do
    n1 <- query ()
    n2 <- query ()
    return (n1, n2)
```

Let's pass it our closure and see what happens:

```
>>> evalState someQuery incrementer
(0, 1)
```

Let's write a different closure that returns some arbitrary pattern:

```
weirdClosure :: Closure () Int
weirdClosure = Respond (\() -> (42, Respond (\() -> (666, weirdClosure))))
```

... and test it:

```
>>> evalState someQuery weirdClosure
(42, 666)
```

Now, writing closures by hand seems pretty awkward.  Wouldn't it be nice if we could use `do` notation to write the closure?  Well, we can!  We only have to make one change to our closure type:

```
data Closure i o r = Done r | Respond (i -> (o, Closure i o r))
```

Now we can define a `Monad` instance (from `Control.Monad`) for `Closure i o`:

```
instance Monad (Closure i o) where
    return = Done
    (Done r) >>= f = f r
    (Respond k) >>= f = Respond $ \i -> let (o, c) = k i in (o, c >>= f)
```

And we can write a convenience function which corresponds to servicing a single request:

```
answer :: (i -> o) -> Closure i o ()
answer f = Respond $ \i -> (f i, Done ())
```

... which we can use to rewrite all our old closures:

```
incrementer :: Closure () Int ()
incrementer = forM_ [1..] $ \n -> answer (\() -> n)

weirdClosure :: Closure () Int r
weirdClosure = forever $ do
    answer (\() -> 42)
    answer (\() -> 666)
```

Now we just change our query function to:

```
query :: i -> StateT (Closure i o r) (Either r) o
query i = StateT $ \x -> case x of
    Respond f -> Right (f i)
    Done    r -> Left  r
```

... and use it to write queries:

```
someQuery :: StateT (Closure () Int ()) (Either ()) (Int, Int)
someQuery = do
    n1 <- query ()
    n2 <- query ()
    return (n1, n2)
```

Now test it!

```
>>> evalStateT someQuery incrementer
Right (1, 2)
>>> evalStateT someQuery weirdClosure
Right (42, 666)
>>> evalStateT someQuery (return ())
Left ()
```

However, I still don't consider that a truly elegant approach, so I'm going to conclude by shamelessly plugging my [Proxy](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/2.3.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html) type in my `pipes` as a much general and more structured way of writing closures and their consumers.  The `Server` type represents a generalized closure and the `Client` represents a generalized consumer of a closure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but most of this is over my head for now. I'll come back to this when I learn more

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, Haskell does not allow the "state" in a closure to be altered. This prevents you from doing anything that might break function purity.

Comment: Does that mean if I declare a variable that is closed over by a function, if I later modify that variable outside of that function and then execute that function, that function will ignore my mutation and still give back the same output as when I didn't mutate the closed over variable?

Comment: Haskell does not allow you to "modify" a variable later. (Or ever.)